# Running Stanford corenlp server with custom models

Tags: stanford-nlp

I've trained a POS tagger and neural dependency parser with Stanford corenlp. I can get them to work via command line, and now would like to access them via a server.

However, the [documentation](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html) for the server doesn't say anything about using custom models. I checked the code and didn't find any obvious way of supplying a configuration file.

Any idea how to do this? I don't need all annotators, just the ones I trained.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the server should (in theory) support all the functionality of the regular pipeline. The `properties` GET parameter is translated into the `Properties` object you would normally pass into `StanfordCoreNLP`. Therefore, if you'd like the server to load a custom model, you can just call it via, e.g.:

```
wget \
  --post-data 'the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog' \
  'localhost:9000/?properties={"parse.model": "/path/to/model/on/server/computer", "annotators": "tokenize,ssplit,pos", "outputFormat": "json"}' -O -
```

Note that the server won't garbage-collect this model afterwards though, so if you load too many models there's a good chance you'll run into out-of-memory errors...

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. I noticed the first request you make to the server will load each annotator's model and you can't change that later without restarting the server.

Comment: The server certainly loads the models the first time it's called, but it should also re-load new models if the properties ask for them... If it doesn't then this is a bug.

Comment: I am newbie on Stanford NER. I have couple of questions. What is difference between Stanford NER and Stanford Core NLP. If i trained one model using Stanford NER, how can i run that classifier with Stanford Core NLP?

Comment: How to circumvent the Garbage 'No' Collection ?